# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager return data in block

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2, afhttprequestoperation

I created an APIController in my application that has several methods that call specific api urls and return a model object populated with the result of the api call.

The api works with json and up to now my code looks like the following:

```
//Definition:
- (MyModel *)callXYZ;
- (MyModel *)callABC;
- (MyModel *)call123;

//Implementation of one:
- (MyModel *)callXYZ {

    //Build url and call with [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    //Create model and assign data returned by api

    return model;

}
```

Now I want to use the great AFNetworking framework to get rid of that "dataWithContentsOfURL" calls. So I changed my methods:

```
- (MyModel *)callXYZ {
    __block MyModel *m;
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //process data and assign to model m
    }
    return m;
}
```

This code won't work cause the empty model gets returned before the url call has finished. I am stuck and don't know how to refactor my design to get this to work.

//EDIT: I don't know if it is important to know, but I later want to show a loading animation while the api gets called.

Comment: Receiving of a model goes asynchronously with http request. Since the method returns a result immediately of course it would never wait for server's response. And that's the reason why you should return the model to the completion block.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)callXYZWithCompletion:(void (^)(MyModel *model))completion {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        MyModel *m;
        //process data and assign to model m

        if(completion) {
            completion(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
// Start the animation

[self callXYZWithCompletion:^(MyModel *model) {
    // Stop the animation
    // and use returned model here
}];
```